# beforeAdd function for radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I had a   dropdown with different items for my simplecart(js) that I changed to radiobuttons. This script prevent items to be added to the cart if nothing is selected. It worked fine before but now it seems to jam up the whole site.
Is there any easyway to fix this?

```
<script>
simpleCart.bind( 'beforeAdd' , function( item ){
 if(item.get( 'size') === 'nul'){
return false; 
}
else if(item.get( 'shipping') === 'nul'){
return false; 
}
});
</script>

<input type="radio" name="1" id="sizeSelect" class="item_size" value="nul" onClick="" style="display:none" checked>
<input type="radio" name="1" id="sizeSelect" class="item_size" value="small" onClick="">Small

<input type="radio" name="2" id="shippingSelect" class="item_shipping" value="nul" onClick="" style="display:none" checked>
<input type="radio" name="2" id="shippingSelect" class="item_shipping" value="ups" onClick="">UPS Standard €25
```

Comment: Please let us know how the observed behaviour differs from the expected behaviour. An example or [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) would be useful.

Comment: Any errors you are getting that you can see in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: after playing around I think it is the 'checked' that is jamming up things. It is as if it doesn't get unchecked even if you choose other options (radio buttons)